(APHORISMES SUR LA SAGESSE DANS LA VIE, Arthur Schopenhauer), sens de « à coups de couteau »
Tiré de APHORISMES SUR LA SAGESSE DANS LA VIE, Arthur Schopenhauer, première traduction par J. A. Cantacuzène.

L'Italien, au moins, qui, enflammé de colère, fond sans façons à coups de couteau sur l'homme qui l'a offensé, agit d'une manière logique et naturelle : il est plus rusé, mais pas plus méchant que le duelliste.

La préposition « à » introduit dans le contexte que confère l'expression « à coups de qqch », un complément de moyen: on tue/assassine à coups de couteau, au moyen de coups de couteau, on assomme à coups de bâton.

(TLFi)
I. − À dans le syntagme verbal (à sert à construire un complément du verbe)
F. − [À introduit un complément circonstanciel de manière, de matière, d'indice, de cause, de moyen, etc.]

« Fondre » a le sens de « se jeter sur qqch ».

(TLFi) Fondre sur qqn/qqc. [Le suj. désigne un animé ou un inanimé] S'abattre précipitamment sur.
Synon. se jeter, se précipiter, se ruer, tomber.

Il fondit dessus comme un aigle sur sa proie (Dumas père, Monte-Cristo,t. 2, 1846, p. 305)))


L'explication « fondre au moyen de coups de couteau » n'a aucun sens ; quelle serait une justification pour la préposition « à » dans le contexte de l'expression « fondre à coups de bâton » ? (Il ne semble pas y en avoir, j'ai beau chercher, rien ne parait logique.)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

La traduction de Cantacuzène est assez fidèle au texte original de Schopenhauer où l'attaque et le couteau sont liés :

Der Italiäner hingegen, welcher, von Zorn entbrannt, seinen Beleidiger, wo er ihn findet, ohne weiteres mit dem Messer anfällt, handelt wenigstens konsequent und naturgemäß: er ist klüger, aber nicht schlechter, als der Duellant.

Littéralement : avec le couteau attaque/se jette sur.

L’Italien, au moins, qui, enflammé de colère, fond sans façons à coups de couteau sur l’homme qui l’a offensé, agit d’une manière logique et naturelle : il est plus rusé, mais pas plus méchant que le duelliste.

L'utilisation du verbe fondre rend bien l'idée de tomber par surprise sur quelqu'un, et à coups de couteau rend compte de la finalité de l'attaque, ce que fond avec un couteau n'aurait pas fait.
Dans la traduction en anglais de T. Bailey Saunders, on retrouve dans fall upon la même racine que l'allemand anfallen mais le couteau est éclipsé, remplacé par son effet, dispatch signifiant tuer ici:

The Italian who, in a fit of rage, falls upon his aggressor wherever he finds him, and despatches him without any ceremony, acts, at any rate, consistently and naturally: he may be cleverer, but he is not worse, than the duelist.

Il est intéressant de comparer ces traductions à celles que DeepL génère :

L'Italien, au contraire, qui, enflammé de colère, n'hésite pas à attaquer au couteau son offenseur là où il le trouve, agit au moins de façon cohérente et naturelle : il est plus intelligent, mais pas pire, que le duelliste.


The Italian, on the other hand, who, inflamed with rage, attacks his insulter with a knife wherever he finds him, at least acts consistently and naturally: he is wiser, but not worse, than the duelist.

On peut retrouver cette figure de style ici :

[...] comme un "animal assoiffé qui se jette à coup de langue sur la source qu’il a fini par découvrir" [...]
André Colombat, Deleuze et la littérature, 1990.

Dans les deux cas, il y a une ellipse pour alléger le style et rendre compte de l'enchaînement immédiat des actions :

L'animal assoiffé se jette sur la source qu'il a fini par découvrir afin d'y boire à coup de langue. (?!)


L'Italien fond sans façons sur l'homme qui l'a offensé afin de l'attaquer à coups de couteau. (lourd)


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
